# Proof that $\lvert x-y\rvert$ and $\lvert x^3-y^3\rvert$ are topologically equivalent distances

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Problem: Prove that distances $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$, $d_2(x,y)=|x^3-y^3|$, where $x,y\in\Bbb R$, are topologically equivalent to $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map $f:(\Bbb R,d_2)\to (\Bbb R,d_1)$, $f(x)=x^3$ is a surjective isometry. Therefore it is a homeomorphism. Also, we know that $g:(\Bbb R,d_1)\to (\Bbb R,d_1)$, $g(x)=x^3$ is a homeomorphism. Therefore, we know that $$id_{2,1}:(\Bbb R,d_2)\to (\Bbb R,d_1)\\ id_{2,1}(x)=x$$

is a homeomorphism, because $id_{2,1}=g^{-1}\circ f$. In an unforseeable turn of events, $id_{2,1}$ being a homeomorphism is exactly the meaning of the two distances being topologically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: $|x^3-y^3|=|x-y||x^2+xy+y^2|$ and $x^2+xy+y^2$ only vanishes at $(0,0)$.